# python read binary file byte by byte and read line feed as 0a

Tags: python

This might seem pretty stupid, but I'm a complete newbie in python.

So, I have a binary file that holds data as

```
47 40 ad e8 66 29 10 87 d7 73 0a 40 10
```

When I tried to read it with python by

```
with open(absolutePathInput, "rb") as f:    
    for line in self.file:
        for byte, nextbyte in zip(line[:], line[1:]):
            if state == 'wait_for_sync_1':
                if ((byte == 0x10) and (nextbyte == 0x87)):
                    state = 'message_id'
```

I get

all bytes but 0a is read as line feed(i.e. \n)
It seems that it considers as "line feed" and self.file reads only till 0a.

correct me to read 0a as hex value

Comment: Well, you're *telling* python to give you the text until the next line feed by doing `for line in self.file`. Not sure what you expected to happen. Maybe instead of looping over lines, just loop over the whole content of the file?

Comment: yes whole content of the file looping is required.. let me know how to do that. TIA